# SVN CheckOut files which are committed between 2 dates

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

How we can checkout the files which are committed between 2 dates.

I'm getting the error "svn: E195008: Revision range is not allowed" when i'm using the below option 
**svn co URL -r {2016-04-01}:{2016-07-22}**

and we can see the log messages between 2 dates **svn log URL -qv -r {2016-07-01}:{2016-07-21}** like this what is the option we need to use to CO the files which are committed between 2 dates.

Comment: Loading a working copy from the latest, most up-to-date revision doesn't include the desired files?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** checkout

- Separate files (URL must point to directory)
- Only "modified in revision" files, because each SVN revision is slice of history of all files, existing in repo
- Range of revision, because each revision is separate independent entity

Beside the fact, that I can't see any good reasoning for such file-set as *physical* object (*logical* object is just `svn ls -qv` with some post-processing) and question isn't related to VisualSVN Server (only to pure core SVN) I can't imagine, why do you not read docs?! Even `svn help` must show you required steps with just some actions (**TBT!!!** written from mind)

1. Get list of all affected files and add it to changelist (by hand somehow): `svn ls -v N:M ...` + `svn cl MYFILES --targets LIST` (save list of files from `ls` /with **numerical** revision at least for START-REV/ to file, clean it, use file as source for creating changelist)
2. `svn co BASE/URL  --depth 'empty'` (get **empty** Working Copy)
3. `svn up -r M --set-depth 'infinity' -cl MYFILES` (update /from nothing/ only files in changeslist, using END-REV as base)

HTH